# Testng launches the browser twise

Tags: selenium

have created only one class and method but the testng launches the browser twice, but while using main method directly its launches the browser only once.

```
public class Testngcall {

    @Test
    public static void main() throws Exception
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\karthik\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: For above code it will open once only, to cross verify i ran your code on my machine its opening chrome only once.

Comment: I would recommend you to add there (@)BeforeClass ( create driver ) and (@)AfterClass ( close driver )

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are two instances running in the Task Manager. Usually, it happens when there are multiple instances running simultaneously.

Comment: multiple instances of what?

Comment: Either chromedriver or standalone server.

Comment: Yeah before it was like that, but now i have deleted that standalone . Now only chromedriver.exe but still existing the same issue